# How do you Compare Key Value Pairs Ruby

Tags: ruby, sorting, hash

What is the easiest way to compare each key-value pair in a hash in Ruby, to one another?

For example,

I want to sort this code so the highest three values are first. If the third spot has values that are all the same, then I want the one greatest
key to go in that spot.

`{"Aa"=>1, "DDD"=>1, "DdD"=>1, "aA"=>1, "aa"=>1, "bb"=>1, "cC"=>1, "cc"=>1, "ddd"=>3, "e"=>7}`

I need the above hash to be `{"e"=>7, "ddd"=>3, "aa"=>1}`

Comment: Hashes in Ruby are intended as *unordered* data structures. If you need the elements in a specific order, you shouldn't be using a hash.

Comment: It's more than needing it ordered. It is basically a big string and the top three words that occur the most have to be output. So, for example, `("e e e e DDD ddd DdD: ddd ddd aa aA Aa, bb cc cC e e e") == ["e", "ddd", "aa"]'. I first tallied them, and then moved them to an array, but then came up against an issue because I still wasn't able to order them the way I needed, and I couldn't get the numbers out

Comment: I may have got it

Comment: In that case, consider posting an answer to the question. We encourage folks to post answers to their own questions to help future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: _"If the third spot has values that are all the same, then I want the one largest key to go in that spot"_ – what makes `"aa"` the largest key?

Comment: How is `"ddd"` "larger than" `"DDD"`?

Comment: Tip: `group_by` can help clump together related keys. Those can then be `sort_by` some arbitrary criteria.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo : Not quite anymore. In the very first Ruby versions (I think up to, about, 1.6 or 1.7), a Hash was unordered. Nowadays the Hash in Ruby is guaranteed to obey insertion order. "Sorting" a Hash means creating a new Hash and putting in the elements into the desired order. Usually this is done by converting a Hash to an Array of key-value-pairs, sorting the Array, and then turning it into a Hash again.

Comment: @tadman "aa" is larger than any of then other keys. You can test it out in irb by just putting "aa" > "AA" or "bb" and so on. Same thing with "ddd", it is larger than "DDD", and you can test that out in irb as well.

Comment: That's not "larger", that's alphabetical order.

Comment: @tadman Yeah, so again...... if you put it in irb, it is literally > (which means larger than) "AA". I am not talking about it actually being larger than. I am taking about Ruby, and how it prioritizes it, and trying to explain it so people will understand why "aa" comes before "Aa"

Comment: That means "greater than", which is a mathematical term, not "larger than". There's an important semantic difference there. "Larger" implies "longer string".

Comment: ok, sounds good :)

Comment: I can see why that word would be confusing. I will change it

Answer (score 3):

One string - last string makes what u want. Add `.reverse` after `.sort` for changing sort direction.
That is a solution:

```
# two lines for test
m = %w(a a a a a DDD DD ddd Ddd ddd e e e cC cC cC cC b x XXX XXX XXX ZZZ ZZZ ZZZ)
m = %w(n n n KKK KKK KKK KKK KKK LLL LLL LLL kk kk kk kk kk kk kk kk)
m = m.inject(Hash.new(0)) {|h, n| h.update(n => h[n]+1)}
m = m.sort.sort_by {|k, val| -val}.to_h
```

Comment: Wow! This is really cool! Thank you! Yeah, that works perfectly it seems

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in three steps:

(1) Convert your Hash `h` to an Array of pairs:

```
kv_array = h.to_a
```

(2) Sort the array according to your criterion:

```
kv_array.sort! do
  |left, right|
  #.... implement your comparision here
end
```

(3) Turn your sorted array into a Hash

```
h_sorted = Hash[kv_array]
```

Answer (score 0):

as suggested by @tadman, using a `group_by` then sorting the relevant groups will get you what you want, although you will need to tweak to fit your actual need, as a lot of assumptions were made:

```
m = {"Aa"=>1, "DDD"=>1, "DdD"=>1, "aA"=>1, "aa"=>1, "bb"=>1, "cC"=>1, "cc"=>1, "ddd"=>3, "e"=>7}

m.group_by { |k,v| v }
 .each_with_object([]) {|a,x| x << [ a[1].compact.map { |b| b[0] }.min, a[0] ] }
 .sort{|a| a[1]}
 .to_h

=> {"e"=>7, "ddd"=>3, "Aa"=>1}
```

explanation:

- firstly we group by the value (which returns a hash with the value as the first key, and an array of the hashes that match)
- then we collect the grouped hash, and find the "first" key for each grouped value (using min) ... * this is an assumption * ... returning the whole thing as an array
- then we sort the new array based on the "value"
- then we convert the array to a hash

I added in new-lines to aid readability (hopefully)

Comment: This is a really interesting take! Thank you! I love seeing inside peoples code brain!

Answer (score 0):

I am so excited to get so many great suggestions! Thank you! This entire problem was to take a string and output the top three occurring words in an array. But, no special characters were allowed unless they were an apostrophe that was within the word. If there were multiple values and they were in the top three you had to pick the one that came closest to "a". In the beginning, I used the `tally` method to add everything up really quickly, and my plan was then to sort the hash by the value, but then when the values were the same I couldn't put the right key-value pair where it had to be if they shared the same value.

So, I came here and asked about sorting a hash, and then realized I needed to scratch my entire approach altogether. In the end, I found that I could sort the hash to an extent, but not to the place I needed/wanted so this is what I came up with!

```
def top_3_words(str)
  str.scan(/[\w]+'?[\w]*/).sort.slice_when{|a, b| a != b}.max(3){|a, b| a.size <=> b.size}.flatten.uniq
 end 
 
 p top_3_words("a a a  b  c c  d d d d  e e e e e") == ["e", "d", "a"]
 p top_3_words("e e e e DDD ddd DdD: ddd ddd aa aA Aa, bb cc cC e e e") == ["e", "ddd", "aa"]
 p top_3_words("  //wont won't won't ") == ["won't", "wont"]
 p top_3_words("  , e   .. ") == ["e"]
 p top_3_words("  ...  ") == []
 p top_3_words("  '  ") == []
 p top_3_words("  '''  ") == []
 p top_3_words("""In a village of La Mancha, the name of which I have no desire to call to
 mind, there lived not long since one of those gentlemen that keep a lance
 in the lance-rack, an old buckler, a lean hack, and a greyhound for
 coursing. An olla of rather more beef than mutton, a salad on most
 nights, scraps on Saturdays, lentils on Fridays, and a pigeon or so extra
 on Sundays, made away with three-quarters of his income.""") == ["a", "of", "on"]
```

My thought process with this was to call `scan` on the `str` so I could get everything I didn't want in the strings out of them. Then, I called `sort` on that return value because the last test case was really big and I needed all the like words together. After that, I called `slice_when` on that return value and said when `a` doesn't equal `b` then slice, so there would be a multi d array that I then could call `max` on, and because I sorted earlier, the values would be alphabetical so if there was a shared value it would give me the right one. I passed 3 to max to get the top three, and then called `flatten` so I had one array, and `uniq` to take out the extra characters!!

This is all so different from my original question, but I thought I would share what I was working on in case it could ever help anyone in the future!!